# Как работает select_on_container_***_construction

Tags: c++, stl

пытаюсь создать свой  AllocatorAwareContainer на примере вектора. И столкнулся с таким вопросом. У меня имеется свой аллокатор в котором к примеру Member types select_on_container_***_construction отсутствуют. Если я в своем конструкторе копирования инициализирую аллокатор который находится внутри класса Vector под названием array_allocator данным способом в списке инициализации

```
constexpr Vector<Type, allocator>::Vector(const Vector& value) :
  array_allocator(std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(value.get_allocator())),
```

согласно [std::allocator_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/select_on_container_copy_construction)

Если возможно получить копию из ***а*** то вызывает
`a.select_on_container_copy_construction()` в
`static constexpr Alloc select_on_container_copy_construction(const Alloc& a);` А если не возможно и такая функция отсутствует, то вернет просто ***а*** без изменений

Я правильно понимаю, что если в моем аллокаторе есть select_on_container_***_construction и он std::true_type, то мы копируем аллокатор из value в коде выше. Иначе мы просто создаем новый аллокатор? Или я что-то не так понял?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]